# ios force device rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, statusbar, device-orientation

here is my code:

```
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
      [appDelegate makeTabBarHidden:TRUE];
      self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"newAlbum" context:NULL];
      [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
      [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(addResultGraph)];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
      // Then rotate the view and re-align it:
      CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 90.0 * M_PI / -180.0 );
      landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( landscapeTransform, +90.0, +90.0 );
      [self.navigationController.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
      [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
```

and with this, from a portrait mode, the new viewcontroller is shown in landscapeleft mode, and everything is ok, but my problem is: if I rotate the device from landscape mode in portrait, the statusbar appears in portrait mode and the viewcontroller remains in landscape mode....

how can I solve this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: works fine if I block the iphone rotation (absolute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may re-implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method and do something like

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

This way you enable only left orientation and, if you rotate your device to portrait, the interface won't rotate

Comment: thanks, i've tried but the method is not called and seems to not properly work...

Comment: ok, solved, i return false, 'cause the rotation it's me that implement, not autorotate